# iOS: Hybrid App with loading html and data from different sources

Tags: ios, security, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

Currently I have a native app that is heavily security tested. Now I want to be more flexible with the user interface: I want't do deploy new widgets without touching my app.

My idea is that the app loads it's html-user-interface and gets its data for the widgets from the native part within my app.

Is it possible to have html-elements within a UI-Webview that get their data from the native methods of my app?

App and backend is under my control.

Comment: Am slightly confused when you use 'backend' and 'native' in your description. Do you mean you want to get data via some kind of Ajax call from your backend server OR you mean, you have codes written in Obj-C that you want to run and get its result?

Comment: Currently I have methods in my app code that fetch the data from my server.  These methods are written in Objective C and use an nsurlconnection to connect to my server. 

My idea is to setup another server that delivers the ui of my app with HTML. The HTML runs on top of my app stack and should be able to call the native methods within my app to fetch the data that should be displayed with the HTML widgets. 

The idea is that HTML developers should be able to make changes within my app without changing the native parts.